# Can a lit-element track a variable outside its scope

Tags: javascript, lit-element, lit-html

In my lit-element I'm rendering something based on an outside variable. How can I know to update when that variable changes?

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
import './element01.js';

class Layout extends LitElement {
    createRenderRoot(){ return this; }

    static get properties() {
      return {
        settings: { Object }
      };
    }

    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    render() {
      return html`
        ${(settings.foo === 'bar')? html`<my-element01 />` : null}
      `;
    }
}
customElements.define('my-layout', Layout);
```

The settings object is being modified outside, how can this element know to update?  I'm not using any other framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index.html file should always have a

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

Within the my-app element, you will be able to use all the features of litElement such as

```
 class MyApp extends LitElement {

      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop: {type: Object},
        };
      }

      render() {
        return html`
        <my-element .prop="${this.prop}"</my-element>
        <my-server  .prop="${this.prop}"</my-server>
        <button @onClick='${(e) => this.prop += 1}' >change the settings value</button>
        `;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here one example I tried to illustrate. `settings` property changed outside of litElement and effected in litElement.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/litelement-can-a-lit-element-track-a-variable-outside-its-scope?file=index.js)

index.html

```
  ...
<my-layout></my-layout>
<br>
<button onClick="_buttonClicked()" >change the settings value</button>
<script>
  document.querySelector('my-layout').settings={foo:"bar"};
   function _buttonClicked (e) { 
     document.querySelector('my-layout').settings = {foo:"baz"};    
 }
</script>
```

my-layout :

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
//import './element01.js';

class Layout extends LitElement {
    createRenderRoot(){ return this; }

    static get properties() {
      return {
        settings: { Object }
      };
    }

    constructor() {
      super();

    }

    render() {
      return html`
        ${this.settings.foo === 'bar'? html`<span> element01 will be rendered</span>` : null}
      `;
    }
}
customElements.define('my-layout', Layout)
```

- I made some syntax corrections

Comment: Interesting. So rather than litElement looking at an outside object, it is being told. So it's own object has been modified and it knows to update.